# Transfer erc721 token to another address

Tags: solidity, web3js, erc-721, openzeppelin-contracts

I'm currently using transferFrom / safeTransferFrom to transfer the token to another address but I encounter this error.

Error:

```
Error: invalid address (arg="to", coderType="address", value="0x0Dxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", version=4.0.30)
```

Upon checking the solidity code of openzeppelin's `ERC721.sol` the inputs for `safeTransferFrom` is `from`, `to`, `tokenId`.

```
 function safeTransferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId) public {
        safeTransferFrom(from, to, tokenId, "");
    }
```

Here's the part of code where I perform the transfer web3

```
const nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(source)
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress);

const data = await contract.methods.safeTransferFrom(source, destination, 1).encodeABI();

const gasPriceGwei = 3;
const gasLimit = 3000000;
const chainId = 3;
const privateKey = new Buffer.from(addressKey, 'hex')

const rawTransaction = {
  'nonce': `0x${nonce.toString(16)}`,
  'gasPrice': web3.utils.toHex(gasPriceGwei * 1e9),
  'gasLimit': web3.utils.toHex(gasLimit),
  'to': contractAddress,
  'value': '0x00',
  'data': data,
  'chainId': chainId
}
```

Additional info, when I change the `destination` address to `contract` address it is successfully transferred, but transferred to itself.

Comment: what does console.log(destination) show and does the destination support ERC721!?

Comment: The `destination` is the address where I will transfer the token from the `source`. Yes the they are both eth address and I've tried the `transferFrom` with success using MyEtherWallet before posting this.

Comment: is the destination a contract or a normal address?

Comment: if i remember good i think safeTransferFrom check If the target address is a contract that implement `onERC721Received`

Comment: I tried using `transferFrom` and it fails when the `destination` is address but when it is a `contract` address it is transferred to the contract itself.

Answer (score 0):

**Long story short : You need to approve first**

In `transferFrom()` if caller is `from` you dont need to approve. Thats why your transaction was sucessful

In `safeTransferFrom()` you need to approve your token spender to smart contract whom you are sending transaction. i.e. smart contract, in which you have written `safeTransferFrom()` function

**How to Approve ERC721**

You need to call `approve(address to, uint256 tokenId)` function. Approve function will be there in ERC721 Contract (You already must have deployed this).

Here, parameter `to` and `tokenId` is same address you are using in `safeTransferFrom()`

**NOTE**

But here maybe address you are providing for parameter `to` is wrong. Try removing `0x` from prefix. And try passing address without string as well.

Answer (score -1):

Your address is invalid

> 0x0Dxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Assuming the X represents `/[0-9a-f]/i` then there are too many x's.

Comment: I redacted my address that's why it was like that.

Comment: I cannot be sure if the redacted address is valid. And that is relevant to the question. You may consider using an arbitrary other address rather than a redacted address.

Comment: I think my redacted address is valid cause I tried to create a token using that address and transfer the created token to my other address. I used MyEtherWallet and I am able to transfer it successfully using `transferFrom` without encountering any error. I will try also your suggestion and will provide more information later. Thanks